# How can i extract values from bs4.element.?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So far I managed to make this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def function():
    url = 'https://dynasty-scans.com/chapters/liar_satsuki_can_see_death_ch28_6#6'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

    script = soup.find_all('script')
    print(script[1])
```

output:

```
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    var pages = [{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/1.png","name":"1"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/2.png","name":"2"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/3.png","name":"3"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/4.png","name":"4"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/5.png","name":"5"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/6.png","name":"6"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/7.png","name":"7"},{"image":"/system/releases/000/036/945/credits.png","name":"credits"}];
  //]]>
</script>
```

I'm trying to extract values of "image" as strings

example:    "/system/releases/000/036/945/7.png"

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a regular expression to extract the variable "pages"

```py
import re, json, requests

url = 'https://dynasty-scans.com/chapters/liar_satsuki_can_see_death_ch28_6#6'
r = requests.get(url)

# extract the data
match = re.search('var pages = (\[.*?\]);', r.text).group(1)

# parse it into json
match_json = json.loads(match)

# iterate through it to get the links
images = [img['image'] for img in match_json]
```

output:

```py
['/system/releases/000/036/945/1.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/2.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/3.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/4.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/5.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/6.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/7.png',
 '/system/releases/000/036/945/credits.png']
```

Comment: You bested me by 1 second. :)

Comment: @Firelord it happens to me all the time :D